Can a Ring Structure Exist on the Natural Numbers?
Can there exist a ring structure on the natural numbers? So far, I have thought of one operation,
$$a+b=\max\{a,b\} $$
but even in this case, the identity element depends on each natural number. Can such a structure exist? If not, can it be proven that the natural numbers can never admit a ring or group structure?

What woul the opposite of an element be ?

The operation you describe does not have additive inverses and gives rise to a semiring (see "max-plus algebra") where usual addition is the ring product

This isn't clear.  Which properties of the natural numbers do you want the ring structure to preserve?

If all you want is $\mathbb N$ as a countable set, then sure.  Fix a bijection with $\mathbb Z$ and pull back the ring structure

I am looking for operations that can create a ring structure on the natural numbers.

Then see lulu's commentr. If $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Z$ is any bijection, then $m\oplus n:=f^{-1}(f(m)+f(n))$ and $m\otimes n:=f^{-1}(f(m)\times f(n))$ define a ring structure on $\Bbb N$. (This is called "transport of structure.")

There is a relatively simple definition, if you don't require a multiplicative identity. (Most definitions of ring do, some don't.) Namely, $+$ is the bitwise "xor," and $\times$ is the bitwise "and"
